# Using for loop to build 10 plots using ggplot() - R

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I'm trying to build 10 different plots showing consumption choices (organic, non-organic) using ggplot(). I would like to use a loop to build these plots, instead of building them one by one, here is the original code when I tried to build it one by one:

```
a <- with(data, table(Banana_Choice))
p1 <- ggplot(as.data.frame(a), aes(factor(Banana_Choice), Freq)) +     
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') + geom_bar(fill = "#69b4a2", stat = "identity") + theme_gray(base_size = 14)+
  geom_text(aes(label = a), vjust= -0.3) + xlab("Banana") + ylab("Frequency (count)")+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        text=element_text(size=11))+ylim(0,100)
p1

b <- with(data, table(Apple_Choice))
p2 <- ggplot(as.data.frame(b), aes(factor(Apple_Choice), Freq)) +     
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') + geom_bar(fill = "#69b4a2", stat = "identity") + theme_gray(base_size = 14)+
  geom_text(aes(label = b), vjust= -0.3) + xlab("Apple") + ylab("Frequency (count)")+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        text=element_text(size=11))+ylim(0,100)
p2  

c <- with(data, table(Tomato_Choice))
p3 <- ggplot(as.data.frame(c), aes(factor(Tomato_Choice), Freq)) +     
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') + geom_bar(fill = "#69b4a2", stat = "identity") + theme_gray(base_size = 14)+
  geom_text(aes(label = c), vjust= -0.3) + xlab("Tomato") + ylab("Frequency (count)")+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        text=element_text(size=11))+ylim(0,100)
p3 

d <- with(data, table(Cucumber_Choice))
p4 <- ggplot(as.data.frame(d), aes(factor(Cucumber_Choice), Freq)) +     
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') + geom_bar(fill = "#69b4a2", stat = "identity") + theme_gray(base_size = 14)+
  geom_text(aes(label = d), vjust= -0.3) + xlab("Cucumber") + ylab("Frequency (count)")+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        text=element_text(size=11))+ylim(0,100)
p4 

e <- with(data, table(Broccoli_Choice))
p5 <- ggplot(as.data.frame(e), aes(factor(Broccoli_Choice), Freq)) +     
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') + geom_bar(fill = "#69b4a2", stat = "identity") + theme_gray(base_size = 14)+
  geom_text(aes(label = e), vjust= -0.3) + xlab("Broccoli") + ylab("Frequency (count)")+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        text=element_text(size=11))+ylim(0,100)
p5

f <- with(data, table(Milk_Choice))
p6 <- ggplot(as.data.frame(f), aes(factor(Milk_Choice), Freq)) +     
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') + geom_bar(fill = "#69b4a2", stat = "identity") + theme_gray(base_size = 14)+
  geom_text(aes(label = f), vjust= -0.3) + xlab("Milk") + ylab("Frequency (count)")+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        text=element_text(size=11))+ylim(0,100)
p6 

g <- with(data, table(Cheese_Choice))
p7 <- ggplot(as.data.frame(g), aes(factor(Cheese_Choice), Freq)) +     
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') + geom_bar(fill = "#69b4a2", stat = "identity") + theme_gray(base_size = 14)+
  geom_text(aes(label = g), vjust= -0.3) + xlab("Cheese") + ylab("Frequency (count)")+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        text=element_text(size=11))+ylim(0,100)
p7 

h <- with(data, table(Wine_Choice))
p8 <- ggplot(as.data.frame(h), aes(factor(Wine_Choice), Freq)) +     
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') + geom_bar(fill = "#69b4a2", stat = "identity") + theme_gray(base_size = 14)+
  geom_text(aes(label = h), vjust= -0.3) + xlab("Wine") + ylab("Frequency (count)")+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        text=element_text(size=11))+ylim(0,100)
p8

i <- with(data, table(MilkChoco_Choice))
p9 <- ggplot(as.data.frame(i), aes(factor(MilkChoco_Choice), Freq)) +     
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') + geom_bar(fill = "#69b4a2", stat = "identity") + theme_gray(base_size = 14)+
  geom_text(aes(label = i), vjust= -0.3) + xlab("Milk Chocolate") + ylab("Frequency (count)")+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        text=element_text(size=11))+ylim(0,100)
p9


j <- with(data, table(DarkChoco_Choice))
p10 <- ggplot(as.data.frame(j), aes(factor(DarkChoco_Choice), Freq)) +     
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') + geom_bar(fill = "#69b4a2", stat = "identity") + theme_gray(base_size = 14)+
  geom_text(aes(label = j), vjust= -0.3) + xlab("Dark Chocolate") + ylab("Frequency (count)")+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        text=element_text(size=11))+ylim(0,100)
p10
```

As you can see, this is very slow. How do I build these plots using a for loop?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

you can try making your data into a longer format using tidyr::pivot_longer(), and then use facet_wrap() to generate all the plots at once.